# Dynamic Entity EF5 Create And *REMOVE OR RECREATE* TypeBuilder

Tags: c#, entity-framework, runtime, il

i have to use entity framework with dynamic table columns(that user can add column to my table), and i need to have dynamic run-time type entity to map my table.

my scenario :
if DbContext wants to insert static entity(like MyTableEntity) that inherited from DynamicEntity, it will create Dynamic type with same name of entity(like MyTableEntity) with "Dynamic_" prefix, after that create instance from generated runtime type and then fill static type properties value to 
instance of runtime object. finally insert method will insert runtime object.
every thing is good and work.
but because TypeBuilder create runtime type and if i call insert two time or more, TypeBuilder will create new type with same name like "Dynamic_MyTableEntity" and DbContext cannot recognize witch class must insert and it is natural.

**my question :**
how can i remove old type that i create by TypeBuilder or renew or update old type, like first remove all properties and again add all properties.

i create class that inherited from DynamicObject, and i will inherit my dynamic entities from DynamicEntity class.

```
public class DynamicEntity : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject {
    //Runtime Type Prefix 
    public const string DynamicTypePrefix = "Dynamic_";

    //Dictionary Key = PropertyName, Value = Value Of Property
    private Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    //Dictionary Key = typeof static type, Value = Dynamic Type, Corresponding static type
    private static Dictionary<Type, Type> staticType_DynamicType = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

    private static Assembly currentAssembly;
    private Assembly CurrentAssembly {
        get {
            if (currentAssembly == null) {
                currentAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(type);
            }
            return currentAssembly;
        }
    }

    //Generate dynamic type from static type, and Cache it to staticType_DynamicType for later use, and return
    public Type GetDynamicType() {
        Type dynamicType;

        if (!staticType_DynamicType.TryGetValue(type, out dynamicType)) {
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = CreateTypeBuilder(CurrentAssembly.FullName, CurrentAssembly.GetLoadedModules()[0].Name, DynamicTypePrefix + type.Name);

            foreach (var item in properties.Where(q => q.Value != null).Select(q => new { Name = q.Key, Type = q.Value.GetType() })) {
                CreateAutoImplementedProperty(typeBuilder, item.Name, item.Type);
            }

            dynamicType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
            staticType_DynamicType[type] = dynamicType;
        }

        return dynamicType;
    }

    //Create TypeBuilder
    private TypeBuilder CreateTypeBuilder(string assemblyName, string moduleName, string typeName) {


        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = AppDomain
            .CurrentDomain
            .DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(assemblyName), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
            .DefineDynamicModule(moduleName)
            .DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public, type);
        typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);
        return typeBuilder;
    }

    //Create Property for TypeBuilder
    private static void CreateAutoImplementedProperty(
        TypeBuilder builder, string propertyName, Type propertyType) {
        const string PrivateFieldPrefix = "m_";
        const string GetterPrefix = "get_";
        const string SetterPrefix = "set_";

        // Generate the field.
        FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = builder.DefineField(
            string.Concat(PrivateFieldPrefix, propertyName),
                          propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

        // Generate the property
        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = builder.DefineProperty(
            propertyName, System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);

        // Property getter and setter attributes.
        MethodAttributes propertyMethodAttributes =
            MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
            MethodAttributes.HideBySig;

        // Define the getter method.
        MethodBuilder getterMethod = builder.DefineMethod(
            string.Concat(GetterPrefix, propertyName),
            propertyMethodAttributes, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);

        // Emit the IL code.
        // ldarg.0
        // ldfld,_field
        // ret
        ILGenerator getterILCode = getterMethod.GetILGenerator();
        getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
        getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // Define the setter method.
        MethodBuilder setterMethod = builder.DefineMethod(
            string.Concat(SetterPrefix, propertyName),
            propertyMethodAttributes, null, new Type[] { propertyType });

        // Emit the IL code.
        // ldarg.0
        // ldarg.1
        // stfld,_field
        // ret
        ILGenerator setterILCode = setterMethod.GetILGenerator();
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
        setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getterMethod);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setterMethod);
    }

    //Create new instance from runtime type and initialize properties with static type
    public object CreateDynamicInstance() {
        Type dynamicType = GetDynamicType();
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(dynamicType);
        foreach (var item in type.GetProperties()) {
            dynamicType.GetProperty(item.Name).SetValue(instance, item.GetValue(this, null), null);
        }

        foreach (var item in properties) {
            dynamicType.GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(instance, item.Value, null);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    //Static type
    private Type type;
    public DynamicEntity() {
        type = this.GetType();
    }

    //Set Dynamic Property to static type
    public void SetMember(string name, object value) {
        lock (this) {
            properties[name] = value;
            if (staticType_DynamicType.ContainsKey(type)) {
                staticType_DynamicType.Remove(type);
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value) {
        SetMember(binder.Name, value);

        return true;
    }
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
        lock (this) {
            result = properties[binder.Name];
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

sample my entity :

```
public class MyTableEntity : DynamicEntity {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

sample use :

```
dynamic entity = new MyTableEntity();
entity.SetMember("MyNewColumn", "this is value of column"); //or entity.MyNewColumn = "this is value of column";

myDbContext.Set(entity.GetDynamicType()).Add(entity.CreateDynamicInstance());
myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove the old type? What error are you getting?

Comment: when i want to add entity it will say : Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'Dynamic_MyTableEntity'. Previously found CLR type 'Dynamic_MyTableEntity', newly found CLR type 'Dynamic_MyTableEntity'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i change my dbcontext and my problem solved

```
public class HREntities : DbContext {
    public HREntities(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString) {
    }


    public HREntities(string connectionString, Type entityType)
        : base(connectionString, GenerateDbCompiledModel(connectionString, entityType)) {

    }

    private static DbCompiledModel GenerateDbCompiledModel(string connectionString, Type entityType) {
        string tableName;

        if (typeof(DynamicEntity).IsAssignableFrom(entityType)) {
            tableName = entityType.Name.Substring((DynamicEntity.DynamicTypePrefix + "tbl").Length);
        }
        else {
            tableName = entityType.Name.Substring("tbl".Length);
        }

        DbModelBuilder dbModelBuilder = new DbModelBuilder(DbModelBuilderVersion.Latest);
        var entityMethod = dbModelBuilder.GetType().GetMethod("Entity").MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
        var entityTypeConfiguration = entityMethod.Invoke(dbModelBuilder, new object[0]);
        entityTypeConfiguration.GetType().GetMethod("ToTable", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null).Invoke(entityTypeConfiguration, new object[] { tableName });

        return dbModelBuilder.Build(new SqlConnection(connectionString)).Compile();
    }
}
```

every time when i want create instance of HREntities i pass my dynamic type and my dbcontext work fine...